# laravel 5.5.40 pagination inside pagination

Tags: laravel, pagination

I have multiple contents with multiple comments each, i want to show a few comments for each content and allow the user to click for more
i have this code:

```
    @foreach ($content as $content)
            <div class="content">
            ...
            </div>  
            @php($comments = $content->comments()->paginate(3))
                    @foreach ($comment as $comments)
                         <div class="content">
                         ...
                         </div>
                    @endforeach
                    {!! $comments->render() !!}
    @endforeach
    {!! $content->render() !!}
```

The problem is that it's not working, i even tried to specify a third parameter for paginate but that ust results in a weird page opening, that contains all the contents and at the en all the comments;
can you please help me solve this? thank you

Answer (score 0):

You put `value` with same name as `array`/`object` change it and also close tag for `@endphp`, and put `$comment->render()` inside innder foreach, Try like this

```
@foreach ($content as $c)
        <div class="content">
        ...
        </div>  
        @php
           $comments = $c->comments()->paginate(3))
        @endphp
        @foreach ($comments as $comment)
          <div class="content">
            ...
          </div>
          {!! $comment->render() !!}
        @endforeach
@endforeach
{!! $content->render() !!}
```

Or more readable change `$content` to `$contents` and then use like

```
@foreach ($contents as $content)
```